# Devise and Multi-tenant Scoping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, multi-tenant

NOTE: The original question has changed a bit. I have found two solutions, and probably on the way to change the design altogether.

In any case, I would be interested to know, why RequestStore is not working (is it because Warden intercepts the message ahead in the middleware stack?), how Thread.current is working, and why instance variable is an unstable solution.

---

I have enabled multi-tenancy using default_scope in my application, including the Devise User model.

In the application_controller.rb, I have

```
around_filter :set_request_store

def set_request_store
  Tenant.current = current_tenant.id
  yield
ensure
  Tenant.current = nil
end
```

And Tenant.current in turn sets a RequestStore hash key.

In tenant.rb

```
def self.current
  RequestStore.store[:current_tenant_id]
end

def self.current=(tenant_id)
  RequestStore.store[:current_tenant_id] = tenant_id
end
```

In my routes.rb file, I have the following

```
  unauthenticated do
    root to: 'home#index', as: :public_root
  end

  authenticated :user do
    root to: 'dashboard#index', as: :application_root
  end
```

The problem I faced is better illustrated through the logs.

After a successful sign in.

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-24 14:57:13 +0530
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"tenant_id"=>"1", "email"=>"user@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
  Tenant Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "tenants".* FROM "tenants"  WHERE "tenants"."subdomain" = 'test'  ORDER BY "tenants"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."tenant_id" = 1 AND "users"."email" = 'user@example.com'  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.5ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "current_sign_in_at" = $1, "last_sign_in_at" = $2, "sign_in_count" = $3, "updated_at" = $4 WHERE "users"."id" = 1  [["current_sign_in_at", "2014-09-24 09:27:13.553818"], ["last_sign_in_at", "2014-09-24 09:26:31.548568"], ["sign_in_count", 44], ["updated_at", "2014-09-24 09:27:13.556155"]]
   (1.1ms)  COMMIT
```

Devise redirects the application to (application) root path. Effectively, the path is the same for public and application roots.

```
Redirected to http://test.com.dev/
Completed 302 Found in 90ms (ActiveRecord: 3.4ms)
```

The unauthenticated method call in routes is (probably) trying to authenticate the user (using Warden somewhere in the middleware???) and the tenant_id is not set at that point. see the WHERE clause for tenant_id.

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-24 14:57:13 +0530
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."tenant_id" IS NULL AND "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
```

Has anyone faced such an issue and solved it?

---

**SOLUTION 1:**

First, I have solved it using Thread.current. For some reason RequestStore.store is not getting set inside Devise methods.

The following code solves the login issue. However, I could not find a place to safely unset the value on Thread.current.

In user.rb

```
devise ...,
       request_keys: [:subdomain]


default_scope { where(tenant_id: (Tenant.current || Thread.current[:current_tenant_id])) }

protected

def self.find_for_authentication(warden_conditions)
  subdomain = warden_conditions.delete(:subdomain)
  Thread.current[:current_tenant_id] = Tenant.where(subdomain: subdomain).first.id
  super
end
```

---

**SOLUTION 2:**

UPDATE: This too have problems. This does not work always.

Use an instance variable instead.

In user.rb

```
devise ...,
       request_keys: [:subdomain]


default_scope { where(tenant_id: (Tenant.current || @tenant_id)) }

protected

def self.find_for_authentication(warden_conditions)
  subdomain = warden_conditions.delete(:subdomain)
  @tenant_id = Tenant.where(subdomain: subdomain).first.id
  super
end
```

---

I would like to know which would be a safer approach, or whether there is a better way of solving this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I prefer rely on a dedicated module:

```
module TenantScope
  extend self

  class Error < StandardError
  end

  def current
    threadsafe_storage[:current]
  end

  def current=(tenant)
    threadsafe_storage[:current] = tenant
  end

  def with(tenant)
    previous_scope = current

    raise Error.new("Tenant can't be nil in #{self.name}.with") if tenant.nil?

    self.current = tenant
    yield(current) if block_given?
  ensure
    self.current = previous_scope
    nil
  end

  private

  def threadsafe_storage
    Thread.current[:tenant_scope] ||= {}
  end

end
```

Then, I use it for the default_scope of the object. Just `include TenantScope::ModelMixin` in your model (but not in Tenant) :

```
module TenantScope
  module ModelMixin

    def self.included(base)
      base.belongs_to :tenant
      base.validates_presence_of :tenant_id

      base.send(:default_scope, lambda {
        if TenantScope.current
          return base.where("#{base.table_name}.tenant_id" => TenantScope.current.id)
        end

        raise Error.new('Scoped class method called without a tenant being set')
      })
    end

  end
end
```

And I use a middleware to set the scope.

```
module TenantScope
  class Rack

    attr_reader :request

    def initialize(app)
      @app = app
    end

    def call(env)
      @request = ::Rack::Request.new(env)

      unless tenant = Tenant.find_from_host(@request.host)
        logger.error "[TenantScope] tenant not found: #{request.host}"
        return [404, { 'Content-Type' => 'text/plain', 'Content-Length' => '29' }, ["This tenant does not exist"]]
      end

      logger.debug "[TenantScope] tenant found: #{tenant.name}"
      TenantScope.with(tenant) do
        @app.call(env)
      end
    end

    def logger
      Rails.logger
    end

  end
end
```

Use the middleware, and be sure that every access to your models happen below this middleware's umbrella. This is the case for everything that happen in your controllers.

I gave you a few leads. You saw that I'm quite strict, and a Tenant must always be set, even during migrations, or in console.

Note that, now, to walk through all your users, in a migration for example, for example, you have to do:

```
Tenant.each do |tenant|
  TenantScope.with(tenant) do
    User.all.each do |user|
      # do your stuff here.
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I got the original question solved much more elegantly using this approach. Thanks!

Comment: This find is an absolute GEM.  Is there a test suite or gem with this?

Comment: This is genius bro. Genius.